# How to make persistent notification?

Tags: android, notifications, persistent

I'm making an app that communicates to an Aurdino through bluetooth. It uses a service for the communication part. So as long as the service is running, I want a notification to be shown by the app. The user shouldn't be able to swipe the notification to make it go away.

Here's my notification function so far:

```
void showNotification(String title, String contentText)
{
 ...

 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "default")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon
                .setContentTitle(title) // title for notification
                .setContentText(content)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setOngoing(true);

 mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Notice that I've called the `setOngoing(true)` but still I can swipe the notification from the notification drawer and it goes away when I do so.

How do I prevent the user from being able to swipe and cancel the notification? My app will automatically cancel it when it is terminated, in the `OnDestroy()` of the service.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a foreground service, while your service is active its notification too

So your service becomes so hard to be killed by the system

https://www.dev2qa.com/android-foreground-service-example/